# Ms Excel Power query to retrive Filtered information from MS Access

Tags: excel, powerquery

I need Filtered Data from MS Access to MS Excel by Power query

Here I need to filter data by column:ID by cell value A1 as criteria

This is the query

```
    Source = Access.Database(File.Contents("C:\Users\Bas\Documents\Database2021.mdb"), [CreateNavigationProperties=true]),
    _Hours = Source{[Schema="",Item="Hours"]}[Data],
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(_Hours, each ([ID] = "6934"))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

I need to set from this 6934 Value to CELL A1

kindly guide me.

PARAMETER OPTION NOT ACCESSIBLE.

[image]

Comment: You cannot use PQ to set a cell value. But you can publish the PQ output as a table into a worksheet. That said, if you publish a single value output to A1, then A1 is the header, and the actual output in cell A2.

Comment: Try the MS instructions.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-a-parameter-query-addf7cb7-ddf0-442f-a60c-cd7280e201bd   I believe the option you want is partway down the page "Use data from a cell as a parameter value"

Comment: I can't edit the parameters option in my query. The option is hidden.